# Mysql insert successful but not visible

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a table called games. People can send invites to each other in an app and then a row is inserted in this table.

Recently it stopped working. When I insert a new row, php (and phpmyadmin when I insert it manually) says that the update was succesful (the query function returned true), but I can't find the freshly inserted rows in the table :(

I really don't know what could possibly cause this. I've already checked the permissions and restarted the server but that didn't solve the problem.

The table has the following columns:

```
id (int)
black (varchar)
white (varchar)
onturn (varchar)
gamestarted (bool)
inviter (varchar)
opponent (varchar)
field (varchar)
timestarted (datetime)
lastmove (datetime)
lastmove_pushsent (bool)
```

and the query I'm trying is:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO games VALUES ('','','','','0','$loginName','$opponent','11111111111111111111000000000022222222222222222222','$timeInvite','','')";
$this->db->query($query);
```

Comment: Will need more information (i.e. the query, table schema and code) in order to help you.

Comment: dose the `SELECT COUNT(*)` from that table increse? is there eongh space left on the srotage device?

Comment: Print the query and see if it is correct

Comment: `FIELD` is a built-in String function name in MySQL. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Comment: @PugganSe The SELECT COUNT(*) does not increase and there's more than enough space on the storage device.

Comment: @Madhivanan the query is correct when I print it.

Comment: @inhan good point, but it has always worked. Suddenly the inserted queries didn't show up anymore ;)

Comment: Like @inhan said, try renaming your column from 'field' to something else. As 'field' is a reserved word in mysql. Use the `ALTER TABLE` syntax. Also, what are the datatype lengths in your schema. It could be that you're trying to insert a value too big for your defined data types?

Comment: Could you please execute the following queries: `insert into games(...); set @id = last_insert_id(); select @id; select * from games where id = @id`? If you will get the correct result than try to execute `select * from games where id = id_value` (do not use @id). If it's fine then DB layer is fine. If you do not get the correct result do `commit` in the first screen.

Comment: @nonshatter I've tried to rename the field column but that did't solve it. I've double checked my data types and their length, but nothing too long is inserted.

Comment: @ravnur, done. The first set queries gives the good id but I don't get a correct result from the second query. I then tried to do a commit, after I executed the insert query, but then it's also not showing up :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved it by making a .sql file from my current table, delete the table, make a new one and copying the data into that new table. I'm still unsure why the new rows didn't show up. Everyone thanks for their input! :)

Comment: Interesting. I have ran into similar issues using Python / MySQL. I wonder if some sort of Meta getting in somehow never accounted for in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use commit statement to make your changes permanent.
Please give cursor.execute('commit') and press shift insert in jupiter notebook